# Before delete trigger to delete entries in another table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, triggers, sql-delete

I'm creating a message board system for an assignment and I was having a little trouble with some SQL. Using Oracle 11g.

I have a table called threads, and when a thread is deleted, I want to delete all posts related to that thread, so I thought I'd use a before delete trigger, but am not very experienced with SQL. Can anyone help me out?

What I've got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DELETE_POSTS
  BEFORE DELETE ON THREADS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  DELETE FROM POSTS
  WHERE POSTS.THREAD_ID = :OLD.ID
END;
```

I've tried :NEW and a few other things. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what happens - or doesn't happen - when you fire this trigger by deleting a record?

Answer (score 3):

Unless your assignment specifically requires a trigger, it would be much more logical to use a foreign key constraint that does a cascading delete.

```
SQL> create table threads(
  2    thread_id number primary key
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> create table posts(
  2    post_id number primary key,
  3    thread_id number references threads( thread_id ) on delete cascade
  4  );

Table created.
```

That way, when you delete a particular row from the `threads` table, all the child rows in the `posts` table will automatically get deleted as well.